# Listbox not updating as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, desktop-application

I am using the same sort of code that worked for Windows Phone, but now using it in a WPF Desktop application.

This reads a directory, then reads each xml inside the directory, then reads the xml and ads the details to _item class.

It seems to be adding each separate item to _item (say its reading 3 xml's from the directory) correctly, but the list is populated with three items all of with the same details - (from the last xml it reads).
What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

C#

```
foreach (string fileNameXML in fileEntries)
            {

                    //read 1 xml at a time.
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(fileNameXML);
                    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Job");
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                        _item.Input = node.SelectSingleNode("Input").InnerText;
                        _item.OutputFolder = node.SelectSingleNode("OutputFolder").InnerText;
                        _item.OutputFile = node.SelectSingleNode("OutputFile").InnerText;
                        _item.Format = node.SelectSingleNode("Format").InnerText;
                        _item.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                        _item.Effects = node.SelectSingleNode("Effect").InnerText;
                        _item.Type = node.SelectSingleNode("Type").InnerText;
                        _item.Output = _item.OutputFolder + _item.OutputFile + "." + _item.Format.ToLower();

                       lstBoxQueue.Items.Add(_item);

                    }
                }

            }
```

XAML:

```
 <ListBox Name="lstBoxQueue"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FFA09F9F" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="80" Width="629" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FFCDCDCD" >
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Job name: "  Margin="9,10,432,49" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF323232" FontSize="12" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="50" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Input}" Margin="76,33,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="270" MaxHeight="15"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Output}" Margin="77,54,0,0"  MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="270" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="50" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="76,12,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Effects}" Margin="374,31,0,0"  MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="270" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40"  />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Type}" Margin="374,11,0,0"  MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="270" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15"  />
                            <Button Content="More Info.." Width="80" Height="25" Margin="538,10,11,45"/>
                            <Button Content="Cancel Job" Width="80" Height="25" Click="ClickCancelJob" Margin="539,43,10,12"/>


                            <TextBlock  Text="Output: " Margin="25,52,414,7" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#FF323232"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Effects: " Margin="351,29,102,30" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#FF323232"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Input: " Margin="33,30,430,29" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#FF323232"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Export Type: " Margin="318,10,100,49" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#FF323232"/>
                        </Grid>
                          </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Items class:

```
class XMLItems
    {
        //Accessor class for properties of jobs. Enables all pages to access the job properties.
        private string _input;
        private string _outputFolder;
        private string _outputFile;
        private string _output;
        private string _name;
        private string _effects;
        private string _type;
        private string _format;

        public string Input
        {
            get { return _input; }
            set { _input = value; }
        }

        public string OutputFolder
        {
            get { return _outputFolder; }
            set { _outputFolder = value; }
        }

        public string OutputFile
        {
            get { return _outputFile; }
            set { _outputFile = value; }
        }

        public string Output
        {
            get { return _output; }
            set { _output = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public string Effects
        {
            get { return _effects; }
            set { _effects = value; }
        }
        public string Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        public string Format
        {
            get { return _format; }
            set { _format = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: am i seeing it wrong, or is it three times the same job?

Comment: Correct, its listing the same job three times, even though its looping correctly through each different job, you can see each job when breaking at the lstBoxQueue.Items.Add(_item); line

Comment: where are you creating your _item? could it be you are adding the same reference all the time?

Comment: I missed that the XMLItems _item = new XMLItems(); was outside the foreach loop (before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` is adding the same `_item` reference each time, and making modifications to it the next time the loop runs. The result is likely that the last job is showing in all positions.

Create your `_item` as a local variable in your inner `foreach` loop instead, that way each item is independent of the last:

```
foreach (string fileNameXML in fileEntries)
{
    //read 1 xml at a time.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileNameXML);
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Job");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var item = new MyItem(); // Whatever type _item was.

        item.Input = node.SelectSingleNode("Input").InnerText;
        item.OutputFolder = node.SelectSingleNode("OutputFolder").InnerText;
        item.OutputFile = node.SelectSingleNode("OutputFile").InnerText;
        item.Format = node.SelectSingleNode("Format").InnerText;
        item.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
        item.Effects = node.SelectSingleNode("Effect").InnerText;
        item.Type = node.SelectSingleNode("Type").InnerText;
        item.Output = item.OutputFolder + item.OutputFile + "." + item.Format.ToLower();

       lstBoxQueue.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats it. My XMLItems _item = new XMLItems(); was outsite the foreach!